# Capture stereo audio data

Tags: swift, macos, avcapturesession

I have a MacOS Swift app that processes audio data recorded from a microphone.  The microphone has stereo capabilities, but I'm only able to record mono data.

In the code below, if I `let alwaysMono = true`, the func setup() reports that the active format is stereo, but overrides it to mono.  Everything works with a mono stream of input.

If I `let alwaysMono = false`, setup() sets nChannels to 2.  But captureOutput doesn't get any data.  The AudioBuffer returned from UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer always has a nil mData.  If I didn't check for nil mData, the program would crash.

How can I get the full stereo input?

EDIT: In captureOutput, CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer is returning error code -12737, which corresponds to kCMSampleBufferError_ArrayTooSmall.  I've examined the sampleBuffer arg passed in to captureOutput, and I can't see anything obviously wrong with it.  But I don't know what to look for.

ANOTHER EDIT:  I tested my code with my code with the built-in mono mike, and to my surprise it thinks it's also stereo, which indicates there's clearly something wrong with how I'm obtaining and using AVCaptureDevice.activeFormat. I don't know where to go from here.

```
class Recorder: NSObject, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    let alwaysMono = false
    var nChannels:UInt32 = 1
    let session : AVCaptureSession!
    static let realTimeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.realtime",
                                             qos: DispatchQoS( qosClass:DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated, relativePriority: 0 ))
    override init() {
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        super.init()
    }
    static var recorder:Recorder?
    static func record() ->Bool {
        if recorder == nil {
            recorder = Recorder()
            if !recorder!.setup(callback:record) {
                recorder = nil
                return false
            }
        }
        realTimeQueue.async {
            if !recorder!.session.isRunning {
                recorder!.session.startRunning()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    static func pause() {
        recorder!.session.stopRunning()
    }
    func setup( callback:@escaping (()->Bool)) -> Bool {
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default( for: AVMediaType.audio )
        if device == nil { return false }
        if let format = Recorder.getActiveFormat() {
            nChannels = format.mChannelLayoutTag == kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo ? 2 : 1
            print("active format is \((nChannels==2) ? "Stereo" : "Mono")")
            if alwaysMono {
                print( "Overriding to mono" )
                nChannels = 1
            }
        }
        if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
            let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus( for:AVMediaType.audio )
            if status == .notDetermined {
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.audio ){ granted in
                    _ = callback()
                }
                return false
            } else if status != .authorized {
                return false
            }
        }
        var input : AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            try device!.lockForConfiguration()
            try input = AVCaptureDeviceInput( device: device! )
            device!.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            device!.unlockForConfiguration()
            return false
        }
        let output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: Intonia.realTimeQueue)
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : nChannels,
            AVSampleRateKey : 44100,
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey : 16,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : false
            ] as [String : Any]
        output.audioSettings = settings
        session.beginConfiguration()
        if !session.canAddInput( input ) {
            return false
        }
        session.addInput( input )
        if !session.canAddOutput( output ) {
            return false
        }
        session.addOutput( output )
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return true
    }
    func getActiveFormat() -> AudioFormatListItem? {
        if #available(OSX 10.15, *) {
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default( for: AVMediaType.audio )
            if device == nil { return nil }
            let list = device!.activeFormat.formatDescription.audioFormatList
            if list.count < 1 { return nil }
            return list[0]
        }
        return nil
    }
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        var buffer: CMBlockBuffer? = nil
        var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(
            mNumberBuffers: 1,
            mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: nChannels, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil)
        )
        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
            sampleBuffer,
            bufferListSizeNeededOut: nil,
            bufferListOut: &audioBufferList,
            bufferListSize: MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size,
            blockBufferAllocator: nil,
            blockBufferMemoryAllocator: nil,
            flags: UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
            blockBufferOut: &buffer
        )
        let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)
        for buff in abl {
            if buff.mData != nil {
                let count = Int(buff.mDataByteSize)/MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
                let samples = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(OpaquePointer(buff.mData))
                process(samples:samples!, count:count)
            } else {
                print("No data!")
            }
        }
    }
    func process( samples: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>, count: Int ) {
        let firstValue = samples[0]
        print( "\(count) values received, first is \(firstValue)" )
    }
}
```

Comment: Found this on the [libraries.io site]: (https://libraries.io/github/fruitsamples/AVCaptureToAudioUnit), _using the CoreMedia API CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer, using CAAudioBufferList comes in handy. The aforementioned API (the one with the longish name) requires a correctly sized client allocated AudioBufferList to be passed in along with the size of the allocation. If the size is wrong you may get the dreaded kFigSampleBufferError_ArrayTooSmall returned (well, that's what the header says but it's actually kCMSampleBufferError_ArrayTooSmall) and null buffers._

Comment: [Here I found this:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489200-cmsamplebuffercopypcmdataintoaud) _The AudioBufferList must contain the same number of channels and its data buffers must be sized to hold the specified number of frames._  I don't have experience with Core Media, but it seems that either the number of channels does not match, or perhaps you require doubling the buffer size so that a full stereo frame can fit  (you have twice the samples in a stereo PCM frame)  Good Luck!

Comment: Nowhere do I specify a specify a buffer size.  With mono, the buffer that comes back is 1024 bytes.  In the AudioBufferList constructor, the AudioBuffer originally specified nMumberChannels: 0.  Changing it to 1 or 2 doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue that could have numerous of points where it goes wrong. First of all it depends on which microphone you are using. is it the one on your Mac? if so, then it is usually mono. However, you could make yourself a workaround to just test if it works and be unindependent on the always: bool. Try out that you record it twice, taking the first channel with mono and making a second recording with the second channel, making it with a different " doubled" code.

second thing I see is maybe explicit type the stereo channels in the setup func, to make sure it is getting its 2 channels and use alwaysMono with explicit == true or false statement. see if you can print some channel info in the meantime during the code, so you know exactly where its going wrong.

Comment: I'm using a Zoom H2 recorder as an external USB mike.  Audacity works fine with it, and records two independent channels.

I just tested my code with my code with the built-in mono mike, and to my surprise it thinks it's also stereo, which indicates there's clearly something wrong with how I'm obtaining and using AVCaptureDevice.activeFormat.  I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Alright, start with the Mac mike. Are you able to clone the code and record it twice?

Comment: 2nd did you try with the true - false in the alwaysMono part?

3rd: I found this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones
look at the input orientation part, where it requires also explicit typing.

maybe you can merge the 2 mono files in to 1. I don't know if you are already able to write files anyway? 
The build in mike is mostly shown stereo, but the Mac only has one. It is easier for M4A files as far as I know.

Comment: 1st:  My app deals with stereo just fine when it's read from .WAV or .MP3.  It can analyze it, play it back, and save it to a file.  I could easily create a stereo file by duplicating the mono channel, but I don't see how that would solve my problem.

2nd:  I don't understand what you want me to do with alwaysMono.  When alwaysMono is true, nChannels is 1, and when it's false, nChannels may be either 1 or 2.  It's nChannels that gets passed to the output audio settings, not alwaysMono.

3rd: the link you provided applies to AVAudioSession, which is available in iOS, but not MacOS.